# Initialize a class with constructor inside a header

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

i´m having this error.
My header:

```
libtorrent::fingerprint a("LT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MINOR, 0, 0);
class TorrentClass
{
}
```

The compiler complains that libtorrent::fingerprint a already defined in another class, because it has been inclused. So i move it to inside my class

```
    class TorrentClass
    {
           private:
           libtorrent::fingerprint a("LT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MINOR, 0, 0);
    }
```

But then my compiler get very strange errors over that moved line, like

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
```

What i´m doing wrong ?

Comment: Erm, I assume the reason you think it's a "strange" error is because `string` doesn't appear anywhere within the code you've shown?

Comment: Yeah its very strange but is the exactly error that Vs2010 gives for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .h file.  Declare this:

```
#ifndef CLASS_TORRENT_H
#define CLASS_TORRENT_H
#include "libtorrent.h" // I'm guessing this is the header file that declares the "fingerprint" class
extern libtorrent::fingerprint a;
class TorrentClass
{
public:
   TorrentClass();
   // your class declaration goes here
};

#endif
```

In your .cpp (.cc) file.  Define the objects:

```
#include "ClassTorrent.h" // the header file described above
libtorrent::fingerprint a("LT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MINOR, 0, 0);
TorrentClass::TorrentClass()
{
  // your constructor code goes here.
}
```

Also, on my team, we explicitly disallow "global objects" such as the instance of "a" you have declared.  The reason being is that the constructor runs before "main" (in a non-deterministic order with all the other global objects).  And it's destructor doesn't run until after main exits.

If you really need "a" to be global, instantiate it as a pointer and allocate it with new:

```
libtorrent::fingerprint *g_pFingerPrintA;
int main()
{
    g_pFingerPrintA = new libtorrent::fingerprint("LT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MINOR, 0, 0);

    // program code goes here

    // shutdown
    delete g_pFingerPrintA;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I really forget this, and the VS error really don´t help !

Comment: Use a `std::auto_ptr<libtorrent::fingerprint>` please, or a `std::unique_ptr`. Relying on manual cleanup is far more troublesome than globals.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in C++.

If you want an instance of `libtorrent::fingerprint` called `a` (terrible name) then you will need to declare it as an attribute of the class and initialise it in a constructor. Here is an example:

```
class TorrentClass
{
public:
    TorrentClass()
        :a("LT", LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBTORRENT_VERSION_MINOR, 0, 0)
    {
    }

private:
    libtorrent::fingerprint a
};
```

> `error C2059: syntax error : 'string'`

This has nothing to do with the code that you posted.

Comment: Thank you ! I need missed it out, i wished that i could select more than one answer, but he posted earlier !

Comment: The two answers are quite different.